# Java List of CompletableFutures to CompletableFuture List with allOf()

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive, completable-future

I have a piece of asynchronous code which contains more methods and I need to make it return CompletableFuture<List> in the end.

I need to use 2 methods:

1. the first method getConfigsByType() returns a Flux of type Config
2. the second one, which needs to be applied to every individual Config object, returns CompletableFuture of type Config.

I want to use allOf() in order to get the expected result, but I have an error and I do not know why: "no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Boolean conforms to CompletionStage". The error is at this line: .thenCompose(segmentedConfig -> finalEvents.add(segmentedConfig));

```
private CompletableFuture<List<Config>> getConfigs(User user) {

Queue<Config> finalEvents = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
List<CompletableFuture<Config>> completableFutureList =  admin.getConfigsByType(configurationProperties.getEvents()) // returns Flux<Config>
                .map(config -> {
                    return segmentConfig(config, user) // returns CompletableFuture<Config>
                            .thenCompose(segmentedConfig -> finalEvents.add(segmentedConfig));
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); 

return allOf(completableFutureList)
                .thenApply(list -> finalEvents);

private CompletableFuture<Void> allOf(List<CompletableFuture<Config>> futuresList) {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Config> segmentConfig(Config config, User user) {
        return configurationApi.getSegmentedConfig(new DefaultCombinedConfigProvider<>(config), user);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `segmentConfig`?

Comment: I added it, it returns a CompletableFuture

Comment: You are fetching a `Flux<Config>` then you map each item from the flux, and you collect the Flux into a list, but you can't get a `List` unless you block. `.collect(Collectors.toList());` returns a `Mono<List<T>>`

Comment: the problem is that here, return segmentConfig(config, user) // returns CompletableFuture<Config>
                            .thenCompose(segmentedConfig -> finalEvents.add(segmentedConfig));, I get an error, so I should write differently

Comment: your error is telling you that you are returning a boolean and not a `CompletionStage`

Comment: `finalEvents.add(segmentedConfig)` returns a boolean while you are telling that the `map` function should return `CompletionStage`

Comment: and how can I add the values to the list in order to use allOf?

Answer (score 1):

You can not produce the list of results before the future created by `allOf(completableFutureList)` has been completed. Further, a `Queue<Config>` won’t become a `List<Config>`.

So, remove your attempt to produce the result list from the stream operation that produces the `List<CompletableFuture<Config>>`. Then, add an actual operation producing the result list to `allOf(completableFutureList)`.

```java
private CompletableFuture<List<Config>> getConfigs(User user) {
  List<CompletableFuture<Config>> completableFutureList
      = admin.getConfigsByType(configurationProperties.getEvents())
          .map(config -> segmentConfig(config, user))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

  return CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
      .thenApply(voidArg -> completableFutureList.stream()
          .map(CompletableFuture::join)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```